# Calculation based on radio button, and some problems

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, conditional-statements, calculator

I'm struggling with a calculator that I want to put on my website. I am a fan and have no programming skills. Here I list the problems I'm having, hoping that some good Samaritan can help me solve the problems I've encountered.

Premise: I'm working outside the form tags because the elements will be placed in different areas of the page.

1. The first problem I encountered is: I have no idea how to calculate the bmr * Activity Level Radio Selected fields
   By multiplying BMR * ActivityLevel I should get a new value called TDEE. This is the result of multiplying BMR * Selected value.
2. The second problem is: For the Mifflin St Jeor formula (BMR and TDEE) I would like to show results based on the sex selected by the user. If man shows only BMR and TDEE Man, If woman shows only BMR and TDEE Woman. This only applies to the Mifflint St Jeor formula as the other formulas do not require gender selection.
3. The third problem is: How can I limit the selection of fonts? I would like to limit the input with 2 or max 3 characters (only numbers) in some fields. I tried with maxlength but input Type number doesn't accept maxlength.
4. The fourth and final problem is: at the end I would like to add two fields that calculate the average of the results obtained. A field for the BMR mean and a field for the TDEE mean. But I don't know the functions to achieve this.

Project: https://jsfiddle.net/snake93/89wtnxj4/208/

Thanks everyone for any answers

```
<label class="mts-label">Peso</label>
<input  type="number" step="any" class="mts-field" maxlength="4" id="weight" name"weight1" placeholder="es: 70Kg"/>

<label class="mts-label">Altezza</label>
<input  type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="4" id="height" name"height1" placeholder="es: 170cm"/>

<label class="mts-label">Età</label>
<input  type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="age" name"age1" placeholder="es: 25 anni"/>

<label class="mts-label">Bodyfat in %</label>
<input  type="number" class="mts-field" maxlength="2" id="bodyfat" name"bodyfat1" placeholder="es: 15%"/>

<div class="mts-label">Sesso</div>

<!--Radio Button Sex-->
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="sexuomo" name="radios" value="Male">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexuomo">Uomo</label>
  </div>

  <div class="mts-radio-button1">
    <input type="radio" id="sexdonna" name="radios" value="Female">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="sexdonna">Donna</label>
  </div>
  
  <!--Radio Activity Level-->
  <br>
 
  <label class="mts-label">Attività lavorativa</label>
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="leggero" name="radiosa" value="1.2">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="leggero">Leggero</label>
  </div>
  
   <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="attivo" name="radiosa" value="1.375">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="attivo">Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="allenato" name="radiosa" value="1.55">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="allenato">Allenato</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Mattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.75">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Mattivo">Molto Attivo</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mts-radio-button">
    <input type="radio" id="Eattivo" name="radiosa" value="1.9">
    <label class="mts-label-radio" for="Eattivo">Estremamente Attivo</label>
  </div>

<!---BMR Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Mifflin St Jeor for Male Formula</label>
<div id="bmr-sexuomo">
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_man" name="bmr_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Mifflin St Jeor for Female Formula</label>
<div id="bmr-sexdonna">
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_mifflin_woman" name="bmr_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Mifflin StJeor Result Field--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Mifflin St Jeor for Male Formula</label>
<div id="MifflinMale"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_man" name="tdee_mifflin_man"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal Uomo" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Mifflin St Jeor for Female Formula</label>
<div id="MifflinFemale"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_mifflin_woman" name="tdee_mifflin_woman"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal donna" min="1" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_katch" name="bmr_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Katch McArdle Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Katch McArdle Formula</label>
<div id="Ktch"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_katch" name="tdee_katch"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---BMR Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">BMR Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="bmr_cunningham" name="bmr_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal CUomo" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---TDEE Cunningham Formula--->
<br>
<label class="mts-label">TDEE Cunningham Formula</label>
<div id="Cunningham"> 
<input  type="text" class="mts-field" id="tdee_cunningham" name="tdee_cunningham"
placeholder="0.000,0 Kcal" maxlength="6" readonly/>
</div>

<!---Calc & Reset Button--->
<br>
<button name="calculate" onclick="calculate()">Calcola</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="resetFields()">Reset</button>
```

```
// Calc-Function
calculate = function()
{
    var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;
    var height = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
    var bodyfat = document.getElementById('bodyfat').value / 100;

 //Result BMR Mifflint St Jeor Formula
    var bmr_mifflin_man = parseFloat(10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) + 5;
    var bmr_mifflin_woman = parseFloat(10*weight) + (6.25*height) - (5*age) - 161;
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_man').value = bmr_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT'); + " Kcal"
document.getElementById('bmr_mifflin_woman').value = bmr_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT'); + " Kcal"

//Result TDEE Mifflint St Jeor Formula
    var tdee_mifflin_man = parseFloat(bmr_mifflin_man*ActivityLevelRadioSelect );
    var tdee_mifflin_woman = parseFloat(bmr_mifflin_woman*ActivityLevelRadioSelect );
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_man').value = tdee_mifflin_man.toLocaleString('it-IT'); + " Kcal"
document.getElementById('tdee_mifflin_woman').value = tdee_mifflin_woman.toLocaleString('it-IT'); + " Kcal"

 //Result BMR Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var bmr_katch = parseFloat(370 + ( 21.6 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT'); + " Kcal"

//Result TDEE Katch Mc Ardle Formula
    var tdee_katch = parseFloat(bmr_katch*ActivityLevelRadioSelect ); 
document.getElementById('tdee_katch').value = bmr_katch.toLocaleString('it-IT'); + " Kcal"

//Result BMR Cunningham Formula
    var bmr_cunningham = parseFloat(500 + ( 22 * ( weight * ( 1 - bodyfat )))); 
document.getElementById('bmr_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham + " Kcal"

//Result TDEE Cunningham Formula
    var tdee_cunningham = parseFloat(bmr_cunningham*ActivityLevelRadioSelect ); 
document.getElementById('tdee_cunningham').value = bmr_cunningham + " Kcal"

//This is Activity Level Radio Selection//
 var leggero = document.getElementById('leggero').value * 1.2;
 var attivo = document.getElementById('attivo').value * 1.375;
 var allenato = document.getElementById('allenato').value * 1.55;
 var Mattivo = document.getElementById('Mattivo').value * 1.75;
 var Eattivo = document.getElementById('Eattivo').value * 1.9;
 
}

//Reset Function
function resetFields(){
    var inputArray = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    inputArray.forEach(function (input){
        input.value = "";
    });
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that most of your [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) are redundant. In javascript, the `*` and `/` [operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#arithmetic_operators) will automatically try to coerce all operands to [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). ex: `parseFloat(10 * weight)`, `10 * weight` will return a number, which is then evaluated as `parseFloat(number)`

Comment: @PoorlyWrittenCode Thanks for the tip, I got rid of the parsefloats and the code still works the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `querySelector` to find the selected radio button in the Activity Level group and get its value:

   ```js
   var ActivityLevelRadioSelect = document.querySelector('input[name="radiosa"]:checked').value;
   ```
2. Similarly, you can query the selected radio button in the Sex group. This variable will be set to `'Male'` or `'Female'` based on the values you put in the `<input>`s, so check against those values when deciding which fields to make visible:

   ```js
   var sex = document.querySelector('input[name="radios"]:checked').value;
   document.getElementById('bmr-sexuomo').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
   document.getElementById('bmr-sexdonna').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
   document.getElementById('MifflinMale').hidden = sex !== 'Male';
   document.getElementById('MifflinFemale').hidden = sex !== 'Female';
   ```

   (You'll need to move the `<label>`s that correspond to those four `<div>`s into the `<div>`s themselves so that they can be shown/hidden too.)
3. For an `<input type="number">`, you can set the allowed range with the `min` and `max` attributes. Note that this doesn't prevent the user from typing valules outside the range. It does limit the up/down buttons to the range, though, and will mark the field as invalid if an out-of-range number is typed. For example, in the Height field:

   ```html
   <input type="number" class="mts-field" min="1" max="999" id="height" name="height1" placeholder="es: 170cm"/>
   ```
4. For a simple mean, just add the three values, divide by three, and round. For example, for BMR:

   ```js
   var bmr_mean = Math.round((bmr_mifflin + bmr_klatch + bmr_cunningham) / 3);
   ```

Comment: Thanks again for your support and time.
The advice in step 2 does not seem to work correctly. The function is only executed if click the calculate button. Consequently, the fields not included in the radio selection disappear and only those included are left to show.

The end result that I try instead is to always keep the BMR and TDEE Mifflin fields hidden to show them only when I check radio selection.

I'll explain:
if radio is male show mifflin tdee and bmr male and hide female,
if radio is female it only shows mifflin tdee and bmr female and hide male.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele Ah, if you want those fields to start out hidden, then just add the `hidden` attribute to the `<div>`s in the HTML, such as `<div id="bmr-sexuomo" hidden>`. Then the `calculate` function will show the correct ones only when the button is pressed.

Comment: Fantastic! Now it's the way I wanted it. Thanks again for your help. I will change my secondary answer because I still have to solve some small problem that I cannot understand.

Comment: Hi @kdau - After some time I have another question. I'm trying to do the same thing as point 2 but with select option and not radio button.

Could you tell me how to change the code so that it can work with select option ? I'm grateful to you, thanks.